# Error message during Google-Chrome install.: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list ([option] not assignment)

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome, software-sources, wget

Ubuntu 22.04

Hi,
I found one other entry to this problem, but it doesn't appear to apply exactly.
I'm no wizard, I'm not even able to clean the apprentice's boots, so all suggestions are a foreign language to me.
The error message reads:

**Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list ([option] not assignment)
The list of sources could not be read.**

Line 1 in the source list reads:

**## deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 22.04 LTS *Jammy Jellyfish* - Release amd64 (20220419)]/ jammy main restricted**

and it's got the ## at the front.
Result on the terminal: screenshot 1, it's a repeated line (probably for all sources?), I shot the bottom because the 2 final lines are different.
wget-log: screenshot 2
I've added screenshot of source.list

[image: term.]

[image: wget-log]

[image: source.list]

I don't dare trying anything else as I'm totally befuddled.
I'd very much appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: Your method is on the right track, but you are looking at the wrong file. Re-read your output, which tells you the correct file, and try again.

Comment: Hi user535733, I'm sorry, but I don't know *what* it tells me. I suppose you mean the source.list? I'm going to add it to the post above.

Comment: Re-read the error message; it doesn't mention the sources.list file; but mentions an entry in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory (which get used too, but are optional adds by users with `sudo` rights. These also included for sources, but none exist on a new/clean install so anything in this directory was added post-install).  The error message tells you the file with the error. plus first line of the file with an error (*it stops reading the file at first error so other errors may exist in file as well*). Re-read your error message.

Comment: Hi guiverc, perhaps I should better repeat, I'm a know-not in these matters, and I might not understand the prompting to re-read correctly. I understand you in so much that I can forget about the sources.list, but the error message to be re-read is the one mentioned here, incl. in the headline. What to do with the re-read information? I will sound incredibly stupid.

Comment: The error message you provide is `Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` meaning it's line number 1 in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list`, ie. file is provided as well as the first line containing an error.  Any *.list* files in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` added by users get combined with the sources.list itself in repositories used.  That directory (*empty on a new install*) allows users to find their additions & 3rd party sources very easily.

Comment: Right, after some needed sleep I finally got you both (told you I'm a dummy), thanks. It's only one line listed, but now I'm having troubles doing anything about it, as in the Text Editor it's a Read Only, so I can't safe, opening it in the terminal with 'sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list...' and trying to do it there won't work either, as you no doubt will have imagined, unlike me. I'm trying to find the most suitable way to fix permission, but suggestions vary, and I'm reluctant to type in the first commands I come across (again). Any thoughts?

Comment: :guiverc - mm-maybe. I'll have a look & try, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, everyone, had to work. karel, yes that's pretty much what the problem is, but I think I got this far. It's only one line in the read-out. Now I'm having authorization problems, the text editor file is read-only, and I can't do anything in the terminal either (via cat command). Trying to get myself permitted, just don't want to continue typing in commands before positive.